# Jackson failing to deserialize simple JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Lombok, and the @Annotations create getters, setters, and constructors for me. I have many other classes which Jackson deserializes easily. Here is the object I'm trying to deserialize to:

```java
@Value
@Builder
public class RecipeListRemoveDTO {
    int recipeListId;
}
```

Used within the following Controller method:

```java
@DeleteMapping(path="/deleteRecipeListFromUser")
public @ResponseBody String deleteRecipeListFromUser(@RequestBody RecipeListRemoveDTO recipeListRemoveDTO) {
    return recipeListService.removeRecipeListFromUser(recipeListRemoveDTO);
}
```

And the JSON I am sending:

```json
{
    "recipeListId": 2
}
```

But I'm receiving the error:

`"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.prepchef.backend.models.dto.RecipeListRemoveDTO (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of com.prepchef.backend.models.dto.RecipeListRemoveDTO (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]"`

Does anyone know why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson didn't know that it should use the Lombok-generated builder.
Probably the easiest solution is to annotate your class also with [Lombok's `@Jacksonized` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) (available since Lombok
1.18.14).

```
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class RecipeListRemoveDTO {
    int recipeListId;
}
```

Under the hood the `@Jacksonized` annotation causes Lombok
to do the following things (so that you don't need to do these
manually):

- It adds `@JsonDeserialize(builder=RecipeListRemoveDTO.RecipeListRemoveDTOBuilder.class)`
  to your class, so that Jackson knows it should use
  the builder for deserialization.
- It adds `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")`to the builder class,
  so that Jackson knows the buillder methods have a name
  not beginning by `with`.

Comment: This is what worked for me. The other solutions did not. However, it is curious, because I have ~20 similar DTO objects, ALL of which Jackson deserializes completely fine with only a Value and Builder annotation. Might anyone know why this case requires it and the others didn't?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that when you use [`@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) in conjunction with [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder), no `public` constructor is generated:

> Also, any explicit constructor, no matter the arguments list, implies lombok will not generate a constructor. If you do want lombok to generate the all-args constructor, add @AllArgsConstructor to the class.

and

> applying @Builder to a class is as if you added @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE) to the class

So, in summary, if you wish to maintain the immutability provided by `@Value`, in this case you also need to add `@AllArgsConstructor`.

Comment: I still receive the same error after adding @AllArgsConstructor, unfortunately, and modifying the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Setters are not generated when you use Lomboks [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) annotation that's why you're getting the exception in your code. Instead you should use [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation.

Comment: I still get the same error with this.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserializer(builder = RecipeListRemoveDTO.RecipeListRemoveDTOBuilder.class)
public final class RecipeListRemoveDTO {
    int recipeListId;
    
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class RecipeListRemoveDTOBuilder {}
}
```